# Android real-time game - implement time unit

Tags: android, real-time

I'll try to explain what I mean.
I'm developing a 2d game. When I run the code below on the small screen it works more quickly than the same code on the big screen. I think it depends on an iteration of the game loop takes more time on the big screen than on the small. How can I implement `time unit` or something else to it doesn't depend on the iteration of the game loop?

```
private void createDebris(){
    if(dx<=0) return;
    if(stepDebris==2){          
        Debris debris = new Debris(gameActivity, dx-=1280*coefX/77, 800*coefY-50*coefY, coefX, coefY);
        synchronized (necessaryObjects) {
            necessaryObjects.add(debris);
        }
        stepDebris=-1;
        Log.e("COUNT", (count++)+"");
    }
    stepDebris++;
}
```

P.S. Debris is visual object which is drawn on canvas. I'll appreciate your answers. Thanks.

Comment: A good reference for this is: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an 'iteration' take x milliseconds by measuring the time it takes to do the actual iteration (= y), and afterwards sleeping (x-y) millisecs.

See also [step 3 of this tutorial](http://blorb.tumblr.com/post/236799414/simple-java-android-game-loop)

Comment: Wouldn't that be near impossible - if you're updating a game world with a dynamically changing number of objects?

Comment: Thanks for link. I'll see it. If I found something which helps me I'll check your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If, stepDebris is the unit by which you move objects on the screen - then incrementing it per draw call is wrong, because it ties the rate of movement to the framerate.

What you want is something like this

```
    stepDebris += elapsedMilliseconds * speedFactor
```

where elapsedMilliseconds is the time elapsed since the game started (in mS). Once you find the correct *speedFactor* for *stepDebris* - it will move at the same speed on different machines/resolutions irrespective of framerate.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Android provies the Handler API, which implements timed event loops, to control the timing of computation.   [This article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html) is pretty good.

You will save battery life by implementing a frame rate controller with this interface rather redrawing as fast as you can.